# Difference between these two representations of input text field

Tags: html, jsp, input, passwords

What is the difference between the following two representations of a field password in a jsp? Sorry if it is a novice question but I am pretty much that... !

```
<td class="inputtext">
      <html:password property="password"  size="25" redisplay="false" autocomplete="off"/>
</td>

<td class="inputtext" valign="top"><input type="password" name="string_2" size="30" autocomplete="off"/>  
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<html:password...` is using a Spring framework abstraction where the Spring framework will parse this on the server-side and transform this into regular HTML to be sent to the browser.   View the source in the browser and you'll see that the end result on the client side is the `<input type="password"...`

Comment: Thanks! So what if I want to set the "autocomplete" = off for this? I try it but it says it is an invalid attribute for the tag

Comment: I said Spring but I guess its actually Struts.  Anyway when these frameworks abstract HTML tags with their own custom tags they don't always give you access to all the valid HTML attributes. That's something to consider when opting to have a framework translate from their proprietary tags to HTML for you rather than just writing the plain HTML yourself.

Comment: This shows the list of attributes Stuts has for <html:password...> http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/password.html or not

Comment: Unfortunately using the struts html tags isn't my choice... this is old code that requires bug fixes! Can I not use Javascript to set the autocomplete = off? If so, can you give me a sample code on how to do that for  <html:password property="password"  size="10" redisplay="false"/>

Comment: You can try some javascript to run at onload of the document to do like `document.getElementById('theid').autocomplete="off";` or `document.getElementById('theid').setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");` I don't know if that will work or not.

Comment: Or if you don't know the Id, there is some code here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/autocomplete-off/ to apply this to all input tags. Its in a comment by Ryan, 4th comment down.